# Добавить в словарь список

Tags: python

у меня есть словарь к примеру:

```
dict = {'key': 1, 'key2': 2}
```

и есть список со словарями, но длинна всегда разная может быть:

```
list = [{'comment': 'test'}, {'comment_1': 'testing'}, {'comment_2': 'one_test'}]
```

Я хочу получить такой словарь:

```
dict = {'key': 1, 'key2': 2, 'comment': ['test', 'testing', 'one_test']}
```

Как мне его получить?

Comment: вы уточните логику работы - ведь в списке у вас `comment_1` и `comment_2` присутствую, почему вы все это в `comment` добавили?

Comment: мне нужно список list добавить в словарь под ключ  comment. Это мне нужно для записи на сторонний сервис

Comment: т.е. первый параметр вас вообще не интересует в списке?

Comment: ключи в списке мне не нужны, мне нужны их значения.

Answer (score 2):

```
dct = {'key': 1, 'key2': 2}
lst = [{'comment': 'test'}, {'comment_1': 'testing'}, {'comment_2': 'one_test'}]

dct['comment'] = sum([list(i.values()) for i in lst], [])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my_dict = {'key': 1, 'key2': 2}    
my_list = [{'comment': 'test'}, {'comment_1': 'testing'}, {'comment_2': 'one_test'}]

data = []
for i in my_list:
    data += i.values()

my_dict['comment'] = data

print(my_dict)
```

если же в словарях из списка гарантированно только по 1 значению записано, тогда можно вот так:

```
my_dict['comment'] = [list(i.values())[0] for i in my_list]
```